# Windows explorer: sort by date modified

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, sorting, date-modified

Is it possible to properly view the contents of a folder sorted by modification date in Windows explorer (Windows 7)?

I can sort by the date modified column, but folders and files are seperated. I really want files and folders interlaced together, sorted by modification date (like on a Mac).

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know how to sort by `mod date` but at least this is a tutorial to sort by the name: http://www.kwoxer.de/2016/03/08/windows-explorer-sortierung-f%C3%BCr-ordner-und-dateien-mit-xplorer%C2%B2/

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can do that. I guess the closest way is to right click an empty area and select "Group By" -> "Date".

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no (native) way to do this in Windows Explorer. It has not been possible in past versions and is not now (and does not seem to be in future versions as of this time). Sadly it is one feature that Microsoft has neglected to address with each Windows release.

Your best bet is to look for a shell-extension that does this, however at this time, I am at a loss to find one (in fact, because beginning with Vista, Explorer uses a different list control, it is unlikely that any will be written any time soon, though [StExBar](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/StExBar.html) is the most likely candidate to accomplish it).

Answer (score 1):

The GNU Emacs text editor comes with a built in "directory editor" called [dired](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dired). In that mode you can press `s` and the directory will be sorted by "modified date". The listing interlaces directories and files.

Answer (score -3):

Just figured it out! Click in an empty field and choose Group by none. Then go to Tools/Folder Options/View and click on Apply to all folders.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work (even when trying your other answer out too)