# Simple alphabetization of files without regard to type?

Tags: windows-7

I want to see all my files, folders, and shortcuts in a simple, alphabetical list, without regard to what kind of file it is or whether it's a file or folder. Is there any way to do this? I'm talking about...

Alpha (file)
Beta (folder)
C (file)
D (shortcut)
E (file)
Etc.

Thanks to anyone with an answer.

Comment: Duplicate of [Windows 7, any way to sort folders and files all mixed together?](http://superuser.com/questions/329127/windows-7-any-way-to-sort-folders-and-files-all-mixed-together) and [Sort files by date modified, but folders always before files in Windows Explorer?](http://superuser.com/questions/238825/sort-files-by-date-modified-but-folders-always-before-files-in-windows-explorer)

Answer (score 1):

Download Everything
http://download.cnet.com/Everything/3000-2379_4-10890746.html

Open the program and just hit enter.

It will separate the folders, but that is the closest I can get to what you seem to want.