# Sort folders in File Explorer based on date of last modified file inside

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

When I view a folder, I want the subfolders to be sorted in the list by the last modified file, not the creation date of the folder.

For instance, if I last modified a file in subfolder Z, I would like subfolder Z to be at the top of the list of folders when I come back in to view.

Right now File Explorer only seems to sort by the creation date of the subfolder itself, not the last modified date of a file within the folder.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows explorer: sort by date modified](https://superuser.com/questions/183389/windows-explorer-sort-by-date-modified)

Comment: @wrecclesham: No, this is sorting sub-folders by their contained files.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is perhaps that modifying a file changes its modification-date
but not that of the containing folder.

To set correctly the modification-date of the sub-folders,
you could use the free Nirsoft utility
[FolderTimeUpdate](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/folder_time_update.html):

> FolderTimeUpdate is a simple tool for Windows that scans all files and folders under the base folder you choose, and updates the 'Modified Time' of every folder according the latest modified time of the files stored in it.